# From m3u8/ts files to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a bunch of ts segments **locally**, with the corresponding m3u8 playlist.
Now, I would like to reassemble the mp4 file, losslessly.

I tried using ffmpeg, but I don't understand:

1. The difference between https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate and Unix's cat
2. The difference between Concatenate ts files before and running `ffmpeg -i "playlist.m3u8" -c copy out.mp4` directly on playlist

Which is the correct way to perform this task?

Thanks

Comment: If example #2 works then do that.

Answer (score 1):

Either give ffmpeg the m3u8 without concatenation, or concatenate and give ffmpeg the resulting .ts. Both methods will produce the same result. Do whatever is easier for you